# Is there a shortcut for Edit Master in Google Slides?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-slides

Is there any shortcut (keyboard or otherwise) for quickly editing a slide master in G-suite?

In Powerpoint one can [shift-click the view buttons](https://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/powerpoint-tip-to-switch-from-normal-view-to-slide-master-quickly/) which works well. I'm looking for something similar for the Slide -> Edit Master  menu option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcuts for Master in the `Help: Shorcuts`menu, but you can use:

1. First, for Slide: Alt+Shift+S
2. Then, for Edit _M_aster: m